# How to pass WSSE:Security in karate?

Tags: karate

@pthomas,

Can you please guide me how can we pass the WSSE:Security username, password and PasswordType in Karate? Iam using the below way.

- header Authorization = { username: '', password: '' }

Comment: there is nothing special in karate as long as you know how to create the XML payload as plain text. if you are not able to use Java code to create the security part as per WSSE:Security, then maybe karate is not the right tool for you.